# How to get ONLY Second line with SED

Tags: linux, unix, sed

How can I get second line in a file using SED

```
@SRR005108.1 :3:1:643:216
GATTTCTGGCCCGCCGCTCGATAATACAGTAATTCC
+
IIIIII/III*IIIIIIIIII+IIIII;IIAIII%>
```

With the data that looks like above I want only to get

```
 GATTTCTGGCCCGCCGCTCGATAATACAGTAATTCC
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't really need Sed, but if the pourpose is to learn... you can use -n

n read the next input line and starts processing the newline with the command rather than the first command

```
sed -n 2p somefile.txt
```

**Edit**: You can also improve the performance using the tip that manatwork mentions in his comment:

```
sed -n '2{p;q}' somefile.txt
```

Comment: In case you are sure there will be no more line 2 after line 2, you can spare some pointless processing by `q`uiting after `p`rinting: `sed -n '2{p;q}' somefile.txt`.

Comment: Good point @Manatwork, and a very interesting tutorial sehe. +1 for both.

Comment: Does not work on OS X. Is `{p;q}` is a GNU extension? IMO the correct answer should be `sed '2q;d'`.

Answer (score 23):

You always want the second line of a file? No need for SED:

```
head -2 file | tail -1
```

Comment: This needs 2 processes instead of one with sed.  So on a performance point of view, sed is better.

Comment: Very curious solution. Thumb up!

Comment: wont work for multiple files, nice simplistic for one.

Comment: I tested this and they behave differently as well - a 2 line file with head and tail would return the first line still, while SED returns nothing

Answer (score 16):

This will print the second line of every file:

```
awk 'FNR==2'
```

and this one only the second line of the first file:

```
awk 'NR==2'
```

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
sed '2q;d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cat your_file | head -2 | tail -1
```

Comment: This is the superfluous `cat` I find myself using at times. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7103887/1672826) instead.